# Map string to different classes based on that input string

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a C++ map with following template

```
map<string,class> mapper;
```

where mapper will contain following data

```
mapper['a'] = Class A or object of Class A
mapper['b'] = Class B or object of Class B
mapper['c'] = Class C or object of Class C
```

What should be the template of the mapper for this kind of map where Class is selected based on the input string?

Comment: Sounds like a case for polymorphism.

Comment: Polymorphism or if the classes do not relate then perhaps `std::any`.

Comment: Looks like bad design, explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: *"Class A or object of Class A"* is not possible in C++ because classes are not objects.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the strings are only known at run-time and that you can build an hierarchy of classes, the easiest option is using polymorphism and `std::function` in order to build a map of factory functions:

Given...

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() { }
};

struct Derived0 : Base { };
struct Derived1 : Base { };
// ...
```

...you can have...

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Base>>> map;

map["derived0"] = []{ return std::make_unique<Derived0>(); };
map["derived1"] = []{ return std::make_unique<Derived1>(); };
// ...
```

...which can be used as follows:

```
std::string desiredType;
std::cin >> desiredType;

auto result = map[desiredType]();
```

---

Note that this kind of design usually is a *code smell*. Think carefully about what you want to achieve - there probably is a cleaner/more elegant way of doing it.

Also, using `std::unique_ptr` and `std::function` may introduce noticeable overhead in your application.

Comment: I'd say that the initialization might take some overhead but once you're working with the pointer I doubt that `std::unique_ptr` has significant overhead.

Comment: @GillBates: it has no overhead compared to raw `new`/`delete`, but it has significant overhead compared to something like "multiple vectors of different types" *(due to locality)*, which is what the user might want/need.

Comment: is `std::function<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` missing a parentheses inside the `<>`?